# Why does time() not return the same value as strtotime("2013-08-28 06:38:47")

Tags: php

I ran time() at 6:38:47 and it returned a different value than strtotime of the same time. Why is this?

Comment: `strtotime of the same time` -- how did you get that time?

Comment: I just set it manually. Then ran strtotime() within a couple seconds of that time, but the resulting value was several thousand seconds off. I tested it because I was working on a "time ago" function that wasn't working and this seems to be why. Does this have something to do with my php settings?

Comment: Was `6:38:47` your local time or the time that is used by PHP?

Comment: By the way the two values I'm getting are 1377688427 and 1377697127

Comment: So it's over 2h difference, check your timezone (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Answer (score 0):

It should absolutely return the same value. Run this code:

```
<?php
$time = time();
$string = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
$strtotime = strtotime($string);
print "time = $time\n";
print "string = $string\n";
print "strtotime = $strtotime\n";
print "difference = ".($time-$strtotime)."\n";
?>
```

My output right now:

```
time = 1377686839
string = 2013-08-28 12:47:19
strtotime = 1377686839
difference = 0
```

Are you getting a difference with this? You could also post your test code, maybe there's a mistake in there.

Comment: You're keeping same value in `$time` while OP was getting value from `time()` and then from other source - that's not the same thing as you described.

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` interprets the time string argument according to the system timezone; `time` is timezone-independent because it just returns the number of seconds since the start of the Unix epoch.

If your system timezone is anything other than UTC you should *expect* the values to differ, since the time string argument you passed to `strtotime` was hardcoded. Your notion of "current wall clock time" and that of the system are different, hence the difference in the timestamps.